# JavaScript Alert and Prompt inside a function are not displaying in browser

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

```
/*Below is a color guessing game that is supposed to run in browser but when I open the code below in my Chrome, nothing happens. Any ideas? I would appreciate any help.*/

/*Below is a color guessing game that is supposed to run in browser but when I open the code below in my Chrome, nothing happens. Any ideas? I would appreciate any help.*/

var colors = ["Aqua", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Coral", "Crimson", "Cyan","Fuchsia", "Gold", "Gray", "Green"];
var target;
var guess_input_text;
var guess_input;
var finished = false;
var guesses = 0;

function do_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random() * colors.length - 1;
    var target_index = Math.floor(random_number);
    target = String(colors[target_index]);

    //what is wrong below? Why is this not working in my Chrome browser.

    while (!finished) {
      guess_input_text = prompt("I am thinking of these colors:\n\n"
      "Aqua, Black, Blue, Brown, Coral, Crimson, Cyan, Fuchsia, Gold, Gray, Green\n\n"
      "What color am I thinking of?");
      guess_input = String(guess_input_text);
      guesses += 1;
      finished = check_guess();
    }
}

/* Is my first if statement correct? Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?Is my first if statement correct?*/

function check_guess(){

    if (guess_input != "Aqua"||"Black"||"Blue"||"Brown"||"Coral"||"Crimson"||"Cyan"||"Fuchsia"||"Gold"||"Gray", "Green") {
      alert("Sorry, I don’t recognize your color.\n\nPlease try again.");
    }

    if(guess_input < target){
      alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine.");
      return false;
    }

    if(guess_input > target){
      alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: your color is alphabetically higher than mine.");
      return false;
    }

    alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color!\n\n"
    "It took you " + guesses + " to finish the game!\n\n"
    "You can see the color in the background.");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please don't (try to) describe your problem in comments. Write a proper description outside of the code. Repeating the same sentences over and over again is also not really useful.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: `if(guess_input != "Aqua"||"Black"||"Blue"||"Brown"||"Coral"||"Crimson"||"Cyan"||"Fuchsia"||"Gold"||"Gray", "Green")` will always evaluate to `true` because the whole thing will evaluate to `"Green"` which is truthy. In other words, your `if` statement is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Several parts of your code are semantically or syntactically incorrect. Please look into the console for errors and use JSHint.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a few things in there to make this work for you.

```
var colors = ["Aqua", "Black", "Blue", "Brown", "Coral", "Crimson", "Cyan","Fuchsia", "Gold", "Gray", "Green"],
    colorsText = colors.join(', '),
    target,
    guess,
    guesses = 0,
    tries_allowed = 10;

function play_game() {
    var random_number = Math.random() * (colors.length - 1);
    target = Math.floor(random_number);

    make_guess();
    return;
}
function make_guess(){
      guess = prompt("I am thinking of one of these colors:\n\n" + colorsText + "\n\Which color is it?");
      guesses++;
    if (!(check_guess(guess)) && guesses < tries_allowed) make_guess();
    return;
}

function check_guess(guess){
    var guess_index = colors.indexOf(guess);
    if(guess_index === target){
        alert("Congratulations! You have guessed the color - " + colors[target] + "!\n\nIt took you " + guesses + " guesses to finish the game!\n\nYou can see the color in the background.");
        return true;
    }
    if (guess_index <= -1) {
      alert("Sorry, I don’t recognize your color.\n\nPlease try again.");
      return;
    }
    var hint;
    if(guess_index < target) hint = 'lower';
    if(guess_index > target) hint = 'higher';
    alert("Sorry, your guess is not correct!\n\nHint: your color is alphabetically " + hint + " than mine.");
    return;
}

play_game();
```

I hope this helps.